# firebase send notification from server c#

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send notifications to a mobile application through firebase, everything is sent from the console to the phone.

Now I started sending from the WebApi server did everything as written in the instructions
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

but I get errors

> Notification does not contain a definition for "Title"
> Notification does not contain a definition for "Body"

Code:

```
    var registrationToken = "*********";

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Notification = new Notification()
        {
            Title = "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
            Body = "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.",
        },
        Token = registrationToken,
    };

    string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

Maybe I missed something in the instructions

**added a question**

I understand that somewhere I have to specify settings such as API Key, but I do not understand where to specify this

Comment: what version of firebase you are using

Comment: @Yegor Androsov FirebaseAdmin 2.0.0

Comment: it should be fine, what happens if you specify full name of class `FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification` ?  or what do you see when you right click notification class and then "Go to definition"?

Comment: @Yegor Androsov I went the other way and implemented via http following the example http://codepickup.in/csharp/fcm-push-notification-in-csharp/
but there is still a desire to realize this through api

Comment: @Yegor Androsov 
went to definition and get into    namespace FirebaseAdmin.Messaging

Comment: I mean did you see Body/Title properties in the definition?

Comment: @Yegor Androsov 
it seems to me that I did not specify the settings for the server address, such as the API Key, but I did not find in the documentation where this is indicated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225193/discussion-between--and-yegor-androsov).