# Notification does not contain a definition FCM in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I am having problem sending notification to specific devices with FCM.**

**This is how I get the specific device ID**

Add Class in Android Project: FirebaseMessagingServiceDelegate.cs

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseMessagingServiceDelegate : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public async override void OnNewToken(string p0)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(p0);
        var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
        var token = instanceIdResult.Token;//(Token Devices)
    }
}
```

1. Each time the user opens the App: `var token = instanceIdResult.Token;` will be changed. So every time I have to update the token on my server? Does this mean I also create a Class on Project iOS?

**And this is how I send notifications to specific device:**

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

```
protected void SendNotify()
{
    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    var registrationToken = "Token Devices";

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Token = registrationToken,
        Notification = new Notification()
        {
            Title = "Test from code",
            Body = "Here is your test!"
        }
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
    // Response is a message ID string.
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);

}
```

2. I received the error: `Notification does not contain a definition for "Body"`

[image]

I searched and found this article: [firebase send notification from server c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032696/firebase-send-notification-from-server-c-sharp). However I want to send directly from Xamarin App.

Hoping for any help. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using FirebaseAdmin?  "The Firebase Admin .NET SDK enables access to Firebase services from privileged environments (such as servers or cloud) "

Comment: Sr, Due to my confusion. At first I was testing on ASP.NET MVC. I have updated the above. It's still the same old problem.

Comment: which package are you using now?

Comment: In Project XF Android I install nuget package: Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 122.0.0.3

Comment: check the c# part of Send messages to specific devices https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c

Comment: Did you see the content in my question? I followed that documentation, but am getting the error: `Notification does not contain a definition for "Body"`